# How can you safely perform blocking operations in a Netty channel handler?

Tags: java, multithreading, asynchronous, netty, nio

I'm building a small Netty-based application that performs I/O operations across a socket connections (i.e. telnet/ssh).  I am starting up my socket server with Netty's `ServerBootstrap` class, giving it:

1. An event loop of type `NioEventLoopGroup` (i.e. a pool of shared threads that should not be subjected to blocking operations).
2. A channel of type `NioServerSocketChannel` (I believe this is required to correspond with #1 above).
3. A very simple pipeline, with a channel handler that extends `ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter`.

My handler's `channelRead(...)` method is called whenever a command string is received from a client socket connection, and returns some response string depending on the command.

Everything is fine for the commands which involve no blocking operations.  However, there are SOME commands for which I now need to read from or write to a database.  Those JDBC calls are inherently going to be blocking... although I *could* use a `CompletableFuture` (or whatever) to handle them in a separate thread.

But even if I did "roll-my-own async" by performing blocking operations in separate threads, I'm not sure how I would reconnect the results from those spawned threads back to the Netty channel handler in the main thread.

I see that the `ChannelHandlerContext` class has methods like:

`ChannelFuture writeAndFlush(Object msg, ChannelPromise promise);`

... as alternatives to the ones I'm currently using:

`ChannelFuture writeAndFlush(Object msg);`

But I can't find any documentation or guidance (or even helpful Javadocs) explaining how one might use this `ChannelPromise` type in this use case.  It's name suggests that it *might* be relevant, but it might not be.  After all, the `writeAndFlush` method still takes the outgoing message as its first parameter... so what good would it do to stuff your blocking operation into a "promise" second parameter, if you need its result to be already on-hand for the first parameter?

What is the right track here?  Is there some way to handle blocking operations in separate threads, so that Netty's `NioEventLoopGroup` does not block?  Or is this simply not how Netty works, and you should use a different event loop implementation (i.e. one that spawns a separate thread for each client socket connection) if you need to support blocking?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If an operation in Netty takes longer time to complete or is blocking it is advisable to perform that in a `handler that uses a separate ExecutorGroup` so that the main EventLoop thread is not blocked.

You can specify that during the pipeline creation.

Quoting an example that uses executor group for DB operation from [ChannelPipeline javadoc](http://netty.io/4.1/api/io/netty/channel/ChannelPipeline.html)

```
static final EventExecutorGroup group = new DefaultEventExecutorGroup(16);
 ...

 ChannelPipeline pipeline = ch.pipeline();

 pipeline.addLast("decoder", new MyProtocolDecoder());
 pipeline.addLast("encoder", new MyProtocolEncoder());

 // Tell the pipeline to run MyBusinessLogicHandler's event handler methods
 // in a different thread than an I/O thread so that the I/O thread is not blocked by
 // a time-consuming task.
 // If your business logic is fully asynchronous or finished very quickly, you don't
 // need to specify a group.
 pipeline.addLast(group, "handler", new MyBusinessLogicHandler());
```